# where to set the font of a qdialog in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, qdialog

am creating a tool with QT creator, that should run on linux only

now i am setting the font for my whole app, this is how:

```
QApplication myApplication(argc, argv);

auto id{QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/someFont.ttf")};
QString family{QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0)};
QFont myFont(family);
myApplication.setFont(myFont);
```

however, am not able until now to set the font taking effect on the window  title, message boxes or custom dialogs...

is this not supported at all because of the windows manager??

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop

Answer (score 0):

If your question concerns the font associated to the title, i do not think there is a way to change it because it is managed by the Window Manager according to [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/72247/change-title-font-of-qt-main-window) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241161/change-title-font-for-qt-main-window) and also [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/40eb8861-f553-4b13-b72b-1d0fb225fab6/change-font-size-form-title-?forum=winforms)

May be a resource to try to draw the window title bar in QT can be found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/3258/how-to-draw-to-the-windows-title-bar-with-qt-is-this-possible/5), which I tried but it is a little of a hack where you hide the real title bar and redraw a text over it and then you format the text using a css.
Other resources but using Python ([How to customize title bar and window of desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377914/how-to-customize-title-bar-and-window-of-desktop-application))

Comment: the font is working in all elements of the dialog, only the title is not taking the changes

Comment: Ah sorry, i understand now. I do not think you can modify the title font of a QMainWindow or a Qdialog as it is managed by the Window Manager (https://forum.qt.io/topic/72247/change-title-font-of-qt-main-window).
Or may be a solution here but I did not test yet https://forum.qt.io/topic/3258/how-to-draw-to-the-windows-title-bar-with-qt-is-this-possible/2